# In as string, how to remove one part which known 'start' and 'end'?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

There is *sku* name in below dataframe, I want to remove the part which start with 'V' and end with 'b', my code  `str_remove_all(sku_name,"^(V).*?(\\b)$")` can't work.

Anyone can help?

```
mydata <- data.frame(sku_name=c('wk0001 V1b','123780 PRO V326b','ttttt V321b'))
mydata %>% mutate(sku_name_new=str_remove_all(sku_name,"^(V).*?(\\b)$"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were actually really close.

Fix the regex using one alternative mentioned by @2evans and it's done !

I share the code using `dplyr` pipe lines because it can be better for you.

```
mydata <- data.frame(sku_name=c('wk0001 V1b','123780 PRO V326b','ttttt V321b'))

mydata %>% mutate(sku_name_new=str_remove_all(sku_name,"V.*b$"))

 sku_name sku_name_new
1       wk0001 V1b      wk0001 
2 123780 PRO V326b  123780 PRO 
3      ttttt V321b       ttttt
```

Comment: So this is the same answer as r2evans but with a pipe.

Answer (score 5):

```r
vec <- c('wk0001 V1b','123780 PRO V326b','ttttt V321b')
sub("V.*b$", "", vec)
# [1] "wk0001 "     "123780 PRO " "ttttt "     
stringr::str_remove(vec, "V.*b$")
# [1] "wk0001 "     "123780 PRO " "ttttt "
```

This also works with the non-greedy `"V.*?b$"`, over to you if that's necessary.

BTW: `\\b` is a word-boundary, not the literal `b`. `(V)` is saving it as a group, that's not necessary (and looks a little confusing). The real culprit is that you included `^`, which means start of string (as you mentioned), which will only match if all strings start with `V`, and in `"Vsomethingb"`. The current `vec` strings start with `"w"`, `"1"`, and `"t"`, none of them start with `V`.

If you need a guide for regex, https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3358272 is a good guide of many components (and links to questions/answers about them).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
vector <- c('wk0001 V1b','123780 PRO V326b','ttttt V321b')

# if only numbers can be between the "V" and "b".
stringr::str_remove(vector , "V\\d+b")

# if any character can be between the "V" and "b", but at least one and no "V" or "b".
stringr::str_remove(vector , "V[^Vb]+b")
```